# Which is more expensive, shell command or manipulating file in python?

Tags: python

`docker ps` which gives the LIST of  running dockers with `<ID> <name> <port>` etc.

We can get the same info in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<ID>/config.json`. (Here ID is same in above command's ID. If there are more IDs, there will more directories).

I need to retrive some values using python script. So, which is more efficient way to retrive the values, `suprocess.check_output("<CMD>", shell=True)` or `f=open(<FILE PATH>,'r')`. I understood, even `docker ps` command also using that file to get the info.

When we issue `docker ps` the list maybe long or short. So, I general prespective, which is more expensive? and which is effcient?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manipulating the file directly is the way to go.

If you know `docker ps` also use that file to get the information, then just process the file directly in Python.

Using `subprocess` to call `docker` cost you an external process, forking an external process is always expensive.

With a simple Python code:

```
def get_container_info(container_id):
    path = '/var/lib/docker/containers/{}/config.json'.format(container_id)
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        d = json.load(f)
        return d['ID'], d['Name'], d['NetworkSettings']['Ports']
```

In `ipython` interactive shell:

```
%timeit subprocess.check_output('docker ps', shell=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 56.8 ms per loop

%timeit get_container_info('<container_id>')
10000 loops, best of 3: 79.6 µs per loop
```